# What string operations are basic

Tags: strings

What string operations are basic in the sense that the other string operations can be represented in terms of them? Here is a list of string operations off the top of my head (not necessarily a complete list, and your addition is welcome):

- reversal of a string
- concatenation of two strings
- repetition of a string a finite number of times
- search/match a string inside another string
- match and replace a string with another string inside a string
- split a string, at some specified positions, or according to matching result of another string
- taking a substring out of a string, according to specified positions (including taking prefix, or suffix), or according to matching result of another string
- ...

Answer (score 6):

There are many "complete bases" for operations on strings. One is based on the representation
$$ \Sigma^* = \epsilon + \Sigma \Sigma^*. $$
In words, a string is either empty or is composed of a character and a string. In order to use this representation, we need the following functions:

- `nil` – the empty string
- `cons(x,s)` – the string consisting of the character `x` followed by the string `s`
- `null(s)` – true if `s` is empty
- `car(s)` – returns the first character of a non-empty string
- `cdr(s)` – returns the string resulting from removing the first character of a non-empty string

The terminology is from Lisp; `cdr` is read *could-er* or *cudder*.

Another basis considers strings as arrays. There is a standard basis for *reading* strings:

- `len(s)` – the length of `s`
- `s[i]` – the character at position `i`

For *writing* strings there are several options. In the immutable case, one choice is:

- `""` – the empty string
- `str(x)` – the string consisting of the character `x`
- `cat(s1,s2)` – the string resulting from concatenating `s1` and `s2`

If strings are allowed to be mutable, we can add an operation `s[i] = x`, changing the character at position `i` to be `x`.

One can think of many other bases. Some will be more efficient than others. It all depends on what exactly you are trying to capture, what your goal is.

Comment: I'd write "coulder" as "cudder"; "coulder" sounds like it would rhyme with "boulder".